# Programming language for manipulating equations algebraically

Tags: algorithm, iteration, equation, algebra, wolframalpha

What is a good programming language that I can learn for writing my own algorithms/scripts to manipulate equations? As an example, I would like to run the following script on [an equation that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJhtX.png):

*I know I could just use WolframAlpha.com or WolframLanguage, but I think it's fun to solve problems from scratch without the use of the website.*

1. Isolate a square root term on the LHS.
2. Square both sides of the equation.
3. Add and subtract terms accordingly to get 0 on LHS.
4. Isolate another square root term on the LHS. [ i.e. step 1) ]
5. Repeat step 2).
6. Repeat step 3).
7. Repeat step 1).

ETC . . .

*Note, I have tried Python, but sadly it's not the best because I can't square root polynomials (using numpy library, at least) and all sorts of other complications with variables and whatnot...*

Comment: A quick remark to *"I have tried Python"*: did you try python with the [**sympy**](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html) package?

Comment: Yes @Stef I tried working with both numpy and sympy, but neither let me square root polynomials etc...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can't square root polynomials"? I'm sure `sympy` knows how to deal with polynomials.

Comment: for instance `import sympy; x = sympy.symbols('x'); p = x**2+2*x+1; q = sympy.sqrt(p); print(sympy.factor(q))`

Comment: With numpy you can turn lists into polynomials: 
L=[1,2,3] so numpy.poly1d(L) = x^2 + 2x + 3.
I can do: numpy.poly1d(L)**2.
And it works fine, I presume because I defined x as a symbol in sympy.
But I can't do: numpy.poly1d(L)**0.5.
because it gives me the error code that the power has to be a non negative integer.

Comment: With sympy, use `sympy.sqrt` rather than `**0.5`. In the example I gave in my previous comment, if you define `x` using `x = sympy.symbols('x', real=True, positive=True)` instead of just `x=sympy.symbols('x')`, then `sympy.factor(q)` will correctly cancel out the square and the square root.

Comment: @Stef I am not talking about canceling squares with square roots. Sometimes they just don't cancel.

Comment: Then what are you talking about? I don't understand.

Comment: If you want to explore something like `X=a^(1/2)+b^(1/3)+c^(1/5)`, a better starting point for a CAS treatment is the system `X==A+B+C, A^2==a, B^3==b, C^5=c`. The equation for `X` can now be obtained by repeated resultant computations. This kind of construction of algebraic extensions and the computation of characteristic polynomials, primitive elements, rational univariate representations is common in CAS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a branch of computer science that is called [symbolic computation (a.k.a computer algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra). I have seen books about this topic in LISP, Mupad, Mathematica, etc. Here are some of the references:

- [Common LISP: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486498204)
- [Modern Computer Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107039037)
- [Computer Algebra and Symbolic Computation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811586)

Comment: Thanks. I would like to code my own computer algebra system someday. I could offer what WolframAlpha doesn't offer.